# Why do we need tangent vector unequal to zero for smoothness of a vector function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis, parametric, smooth-functions

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkHk2.png)

My textbook gives this definition of smoothness of a $\vec r(t)$ on an interval $I$ of $t$. Why do we need $\vec r'(t) \neq\vec0$ on $I$?

Comment: It says $\mathbf{r}'(t) \ne 0$, not $\mathbf{r}(t) \ne 0$. To see why, look at the defintion of $\mathbf{T}(t)$.

Comment: @Joe What does the definition of $\vec T(t)$ have to do with smoothness? Does $\vec r' = \vec 0$ give some curve not smooth?

Comment: Do either of these answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473797/conditions-for-a-smooth-parametric-curve or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806853/why-does-a-parametric-curve-need-to-be-smooth-for-line-integrals

Comment: You can think of a tangent vector as describing the direction an object moving along a path it is traveling, and the length of the tangent vector as its speed. If at any point the speed is zero, the object is free to abruptly change direction and then proceed on its way. In this case $\mathbf T$ will be discontinuous, as it measures only the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$x(t)=\begin{cases}0&0<t\leq1\\(t-1)^2&1<t<2\end{cases}$ and $y(t)=\begin{cases}(1-t)^2&0<t\leq1\\0&1<t<2\end{cases}$

The path goes from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$, made up of two line segments with a right angle at the origin at $t=1$.

Now the vector derivative $\vec r'(1)=(0,0)$ at the origin (and is defined everywhere else of course), but we wouldn't want to call this motion "smooth"; it has a sharp corner at the origin.

Comment: For a vector function traversed exactly once by t on an interval and differentiable on that interval, does $\vec r'=0$ always give such a sharp corner? Could you please provide more examples?

Comment: @TFR no, you could have a smooth path and a particle that moves along it and slows to a instantaneous speed of $0$ at some point. For example, move along the curve $y=x^2$ by $(x,y) = (t^3, t^6)$ for $-1 < t < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf{T}$ has $|\mathbf{r}'|$ in the denominator, the latter vanishing would leave the tangent vector undefined. A smooth curve should have a well-defined tangent everywhere.